# How to solve this cyclic dependency problem?

Tags: circular-dependency

I have a Base class that all other classes inherit from, including the User class. However, in the Base class I need to capture the createdBy, updatedBy, and deletedBy fields which all are going to reference Users. Therefore, I need to reference User from within Base for the fields, and I need to reference Base from within User as super class. This is causing a cyclic dependency that I am not sure how to resolve?

Note: I am using abstract classes instead of interfaces in TypeScript because I need to annotate them with decorators.

Comment: Why does the cyclical dependency pose a problem?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question by adding some code.  But as soon as you add the code, it may appear that it's a coding question that is out of scope here and should go to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question *as stated*, you can lift the dependency on the user class by providing all classes an interface to read the user's identity. The advantage here is that we can avoid all classes having knowledge of the *entire* user class. I am speculating they only need to read some property of the user for the purpose of change audit.

With my limited knowledge of Typescript, you would need to inject into classes

```
interface ChangeAudit {
    readonly userId: string;
}
```

You can also inject a function (called a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function))

Answer (score 0):

`createdBy`, `updatedBy`, and `deletedBy` are not intrinsic properties of all (domain) objects that you intend to derive from `Base`.

Create a `ChangeHistory` object that accepts a type derived from `Base`.  These `ChangeHistory`-objects contain `Changes` such as `Creation`, `Update`, and `Deletion`. The `Changes` contain a reference to the `User` affecting the change (and perhaps to the object as it was at that time in its history).
This breaks the cycle